# Run a method periodically using ktx handler extensions

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, postdelayed, android-ktx

UPDATE: Clarification, I am looking for an extension to run a function every 1000 ms for example, without needing to use `handler.postDelayed` twice.

I've recently started using the android-ktx Kotlin extensions. And I've run into the handler extensions which very neatly converts

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, delayInMillis)
```

into

```
handler.postDelayed(delayInMillis = 200L) {
    // some action
}
```

The problem I've run into is how to convert the following code, to use the ktx extensions. Is it even possible?

```
handler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        doSomething()
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
    }
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a part of the core.ktx package

you need to make sure it is included in your gradle file

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0"
```

or more relevant/recent version

Once you do, you can convert:

```
handler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        doSomething()
    }
}, 1000)
```

to

```
handler.postDelayed(delayInMillis = 200L) {
    doSomething()
}
```

to run this more than once just:

```
while true {
  handler.postDelayed(delayInMillis = 200L) {
      doSomething()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I'm trying to achieve is for a task to be executed every 1000 ms for example. The solution you provided will run it only once.

Comment: @AleksNine I just saw this and you probably figured this out by now. One would simply do:

while true { 
    handler.postDelayed(delayInMillis = 200L) {
    doSomething()
} }

:)
no?

Comment: I don't remember what I ended up using, but this sounds like a good solution. Do you mind updating the answer as well?

Comment: @AleksNine that's not what the question is about, or at least not the way it is stated. So I'd be hesitant to provide an answer to a question that was never actually asked.

Comment: Did you see my clarification? "UPDATE: Clarification, I am looking for an extension to run a function every 1000 ms for example, without needing to use handler.postDelayed twice."
That can be achieved following your approach using the while true right?